Taking the first value from a split in the last line of a .txt
I'm trying to make a method in my filemanager class read the last line with text in my pedidos.txt file:
"0,1,2,44.5,1
1,2,3,54.25,3
"
the first number of the line is supposed to be the id, the method would read the last line with text, store the value of of it using split, add 1 to it and set the return variable "proxId" with it.
public static int proxId() throws IOException{
        int proxId = 0;

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("-filepath-pedidos.txt"));
        String linha = "";

        while ((linha = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
            var aaa = linha.split(",");
            proxId = Integer.parseInt(aaa[0])+1;
        }
        
        return proxId;
    }

However, I'm getting the following error:
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:675)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:781)
at file_manager.FileManager.proxId(FileManager.java:41)"
I knew from the start that the assignment of value to proxId would probably not work like that, but tried it just in case, as you can see, it didn't work. How do i fix my code here?

...store the value of of it using split... The value of what? Are you talking about the first number value of the line?

Your quotations mark placements are rather odd in that they span several lines with what appears to be an empty line in the middle.   What purpose do they serve and how do they relate to your task?

storing the value of the id using split, the first number value of the line, and my quotation mark placement is deliberate, that is actually how my program writes the lines in another method,  so i thought it would be important to know

It's good practice to look more closely to what the exception message tells you because it will give you the root cause of the problem. In your case, you are parsing an empty string "" as an Integer.
You might need to do the following to figure out the problem:

Clean your input file such as removing extra space so you're sure to parse an Integer
Figure out which line throws the error. You have to create a counter and use System.out.print method.


You need to make sure the data being read is clean enough to be accepted by the Integer.parseInt() method. Read the comments in code below:
public static int proxId() throws IOException{
    int proxId = 0;

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("-filepath-pedidos.txt"));
    String linha = "";

    while ((linha = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
        /* Remove any `possible` leading or trailing whitespaces, 
           tabs, etc from read file line:       */
        linha = linha.trim();
        
        // Skip past blank file lines (if any):
        if (linha.isEmpty()) {
            continue;
        }
        
        /* Split the file data line. Take care of any possible type 
           of whitespacing on either side of comma delimiter. The
           .parseInt() method wants nothing to do with anything 
           other than a string representation of a integer value: */
        String[] aaa = linha.split("\\s*,\\s*");
        
        // Convert the first String[] array element to `int` and add 1:
        proxId = Integer.parseInt(aaa[0])+1;
    }
    
    return proxId;
}

